# Android: Populate a a ListView from a Database

Tags: android, sqlite, listview

I have a SQLite Database that I want to use to populate a ListView, but I can't for the life of me figure out how to do that. Based on various internet sources (other questions/tutorials/etc.), I've been able to get this code, but it's clearly not working, as I'm now not even able to open the app in the emulator:

**populateListView method**

```
public void populateListView() {
    Cursor cursor = db.getAllContacts();
    String[] fromFieldNames = new String[] {DBAdapter.KEY_ROWID, DBAdapter.KEY_LOCATION, DBAdapter.KEY_TIME};
    int[] toViewIds = new int[] {R.id.textView3, R.id.textView2, R.id.textView4};
    SimpleCursorAdapter myCursorAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
            R.layout.list_view_layout, cursor, fromFieldNames, toViewIds, 0);

    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    listView.setAdapter(myCursorAdapter);
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/TableLayout">


<Button
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Set New Alarm"
    android:id="@+id/setAlarmButton"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:onClick="onClickSetAlarm" />

<ListView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/listView" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**list_view_layout.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="New Text"
    android:id="@+id/textView2" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="New Text"
    android:id="@+id/textView3" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="New Text"
    android:id="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />
</LinearLayout>
```

I'm fairly certain that the issue isn't with the code for the DBAdapter, as it was working fine before I added this bit of code (I had it display a Toast with the data).

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a **SimpleCursorAdapter**

```
Cursor cursor = obj.fetchAllNames();
        registerForContextMenu(lv);

        String[] columns = new String[] {
                obj.KEY_MAIL,
                obj.KEY_NAME

              };


          // the XML defined views which the data will be bound to
          int[] to = new int[] {
            R.id.tvname,
            R.id.tvemail

          };

          // create the adapter using the cursor pointing to the desired data
          //as well as the layout information
          try{
          dataAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
            this, R.layout.viewusertext,cursor,columns,
            to,
            0);
          }catch(Exception e)
          {e.printStackTrace();}

          lv.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
```

where lv is the listview and dataAdapter is **private SimpleCursorAdapter dataAdapter;**

The query to retrieve desired element you want to show in the list:

```
public Cursor fetchAllNames() {

          Cursor mCursor = app.myDbHelper.MyDB().query("reg", new String[] {"email as _id","fname"},
            null, null, null, null, null);
          try{

          if (mCursor != null) {
           mCursor.moveToFirst();
          }
          return mCursor;
          }catch(Exception e)
          {
              return mCursor;
          }
         }
```

**"reg"** is the table name.

Note:while using simplecursoradapter you should use the primary key as `_id`.In my case email is primary key and I have defined it as   **public static final String KEY_MAIL="_id";**

Comment: The good news is, at least now the console is admitting there's an error. It's giving me a NullPointerException on line Cursor cursor = db.fetchAllNames(); Would you have any idea why that's happening? Thanks for all the help!

Comment: Check your "db"...it is the culprit.

Comment: also dont forget to define your primary key as _id.

Comment: This was a huge "D'oh" moment on my part. Long story short, I was calling my populateListView method in onCreate, but didn't create the DB until onResume. Hours of time spent, and all I had to do was cut and paste 1 line... :P Thank you so much for your help, I probably would have spent hours more banging my head on the wall had you not pointed that out to me!

Answer (score 0):

This question I answered just yesterday. The easiest way to create `CursorLoader`, which will load your data in background from DB only once when activity creates and easy to set adapter: just form columns "from" (`DB.COLUMN_NAME`) and "to" (`R.id.textviewToDisplay`).
Check please this answer.
[retriveing data from exisint sqlite database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27913827/retriveing-data-from-exisint-sqlite-database/27913969#27913969)